# how to wipe a filesystem on AIX

Tags: filesystems, aix

My company is selling some old AIX systems, and they want me to wipe all data from them.  Not sure of the best way to do that.  I'm guessing it would go something like this:

1. Unmount the filesystem
2. lookup the 'hdisk#" device in fstab - and comment it out.
3. use dd to copy /dev/null to the device

What I'm not sure about is whether the whole logical volume manager complicates things further than that.  I.e., is it correct to treat the /dev/hdisk# device like a physical disk for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can boot from [Standalone Diagnostics CD](https://www14.software.ibm.com/support/customercare/sas/f/diags/download/home.html) and wipe the drives. You have options to format and certify, format without certify and erase. You can run each option more than one time if you need.

Answer (score 0):

After unmounting the file systems you should do an `exportvg <your_vg>`, otherwise you get complaints when rebooting the system (although, taking into account you are selling them, this is probably not your concern any more).

*After* removing the VG from the system you can wipe the disks using `dd` as you described.

(It is a common misconception that you have to wipe more than once. Just do it correctly and once is enough.)